# Enter preferred shell when you cannot change the default shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix

In my production environment, my default shell is an old version of csh and I cannot change it. How can I correctly login to my preferred shell? In particular, I would like to use bash. However the system bash is also very old so I compiled a newer version in ~/bin. The perfect scenario will be, I am using ~/bin/bash after login (e.g., ssh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put something like:

```
exec ~/bin/bash
```

in your login script (that's `.login` for csh).

Comment: Thanks. The .cshrc in my home is fixed and turns out .login is the place I should go.

Answer (score 6):

Inside your `.cshrc` you could put an `exec ~/bin/bash`.

This executes bash when csh is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

you need to be able to edit your `/etc/passwd` file

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

the last part is the shell loaded on login, If you want to use one in your home dir change the /bin/bash to new shell